# Confused about HVAC wires

Tags: hvac, thermostat, nest

My townhome is using a heat pump and it's currently connected to a honeywell 3000 thermostat. I bought a gen 3 nest and from what I can tell, it's compatible. However, I'm a bit confused about my white, blue and brown wire. The G, Y and R wires make sense, but the others I'm not too sure about. I even have a black wire not hooked up to anything, but I think I'll leave that disconnected. Can anyone tell me how I should connect the W, B and Brown wire in the nest?

Picture included for detail. Every site I've read seems to suggest the Blue wire should be connected to the C port, but on my thermostat, the C is connected with the brown wire. Help!

Thank you,
Pete

EDIT: added what seem to be schematic diagrams.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace/air-handler please?

Comment: The diagrams are useful, but we also need photos of the actual connections where the thermostat cable hooks up to the air handler

Comment: Ok, it's in a really tight spot, but I'm assuming if I remove the face plate that the last schematic is on, I'd see those wires? Should probably kill the breaker before hand to be safe even if I'm just taking a photo?

Comment: Yes, and yes you should shut the air handler off